# Reshape pandas df of x,y,z in columns to x index, y header, and z values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas df with x (latitudes), y (longitudes), and z (topography/elevation).

I want to plot a 3D surface plot but to do that I need a 2D z array whereas I have a 1D array (1 column).

Is there a way to pivot the dataframe so that the latitudes are the index, longitudes are the header and z are the values in the table?

I tried:

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='Pt_Latitude', columns='Pt_Longitude', values='topography')
```

but it gives me an index error:

```
Pt_Longitude  Pt_Latitude  topography    Coordinated_Universal_Time  S
0    272.799970   -45.261200     2670.92  2009-07-20T12:12:00.90412170  1
1    272.800520   -45.261986     2677.35  2009-07-20T12:12:00.90412170  2
2    272.798841   -45.261578     2670.04  2009-07-20T12:12:00.90412170  3
3    272.799396   -45.260423     2663.68  2009-07-20T12:12:00.90412170  4
4    272.801063   -45.260832     2671.67  2009-07-20T12:12:00.90412170  5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catalan.py", line 28, in <module>
    newdf = df.pivot(index='Pt_Latitude', columns='Pt_Longitude', values='topography')
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5923, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 450, in pivot
    return indexed.unstack(columns)
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3550, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 419, in unstack
    constructor=obj._constructor_expanddim,
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "C:\Users\polyq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 176, in _make_selectors
    mask.put(selector, True)
IndexError: index 571859901 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 571829246
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: We need the full error code.

Comment: @IgorRivin IndexError: index 571859901 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 571829246 which I don't understand as the three columns are the same length pre pivot

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry! I added the ouput to the question. Dropping the extra columns doesn't seem to affect the pivot output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using the wrong tool here. The line works fine with a tiny dataframe like the one in the example, but produces a dataframe of size len(df)*len(df)! That means that you are likely to be bitten by a memory error.

Long story made short: I can see no way to pivot a large dataframe according to your requirement because it will exhaust the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `...plt.plot_surface(*list(df.values), ...)`?

Comment: I tried that but it requires a 2d Z argument which is why I'm trying to pivot the df.

Comment: What does a "2d Z" argument mean? You have a collection of points `(x, y, z)`. See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html

Comment: z for a surface 3d plot has to be a 2 dimensional array like in that example. I just have the points as you said so I can make a 3d scatter plot but not a surface plot without reshaping the data.